# OpenAI GPT-3 API: How to make a model remember past conversations?

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3

Is there a way to train a *Large Language Model* (LLM) to store a specific context? For example, I had a long story I want to ask questions about, but I don't want to put the whole story in every prompt. How can I make the LLM "remember the story"?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: there is a lot of talk on how LLMS might be doing this, i'm interested in training it. http://ai.stanford.edu/blog/understanding-incontext/#f1

Answer (score 6):

Taking into account that GPT-3 models have no parameter that enables memorization of  past conversations, it seems the only way at the moment to "memorize" past conversations is to **include past conversations in the prompt**.

If we take a look at the following [example](https://thoughtblogger.com/continuing-a-conversation-with-a-chatbot-using-gpt/):

```
You are a friendly support person. The customer will ask you questions, and you will provide polite responses

Q: My phone won't start. What do I do? <-- This is a past question
A: Try plugging your phone into the charger for an hour and then turn it on. The most common cause for a phone not starting is that the battery is dead.

Q: I've tried that. What else can I try? <-- This is a past question
A: Hold the button in for 15 seconds. It may need a reset.

Q: I did that. It worked, but the screen is blank. <-- This is a current question
A:
```

**Rule to follow:**

- Include prompt-completion pairs in the prompt, with the oldest conversations at the top.

**The problem you'll face:**

- You will hit a token limit at some point (if you chat long enough). Each GPT-3 model has a [maximum number of tokens](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3) you can pass to it. In the case of `text-davinci-003`, it is `4096` tokens. When you hit this limit, the OpenAI API will throw an error. When this happens, you need to reduce the number of past prompt-completion pairs (e.g., include only the most recent 4 past prompt-completion pairs).

**Pros:**

- By including past prompt-completion pairs in the prompt, we are able to give
  GPT-3 models the context of the conversation.

**Cons:**

- What if a user asks a question that relates to a conversation that occurred more than 4 prompt-completion pairs ago?
- Including past prompt-completion pairs in the prompt will cost (a lot of) money!

Comment: yes, i'm deep in prompt engineering, so i appreciate the information here.  most interested in storing context, rather than including it in the prompt. but good advice

Comment: I'm wondering if [fine tuning](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning) might be an option.

Comment: @Rubén no. since fine tuning is a more generic way to train your model, the model still does not know what the user will ask and what it asked (in this example) 4 questions before.